# How to display more items in access 2007

Tags: windows, microsoft-access-2007

I have this template "Customer Database Support" downloaded from the MS website, and i would like to know if you can select more items in one box instead of only one.

For example, there is a table "Cases" and in this table there is a field "Assigned To", now at the moment I can only select one name of the employee for the "Assigned To" and I want to select more than one. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is a simple NO. In this example database, it seems that only one person can be assigned to one case. Thus it is not possible to select more than one name from the drop down list and add them to the same case.